# How do i know when my Control is done being initialized?

Tags: .net, winforms, controls

i have a .NET control which a user can drop on a form.

Visual Studio creates a `InitializeComponent`, which is called from the hosting form's constructor:

```
public EditItemForm()
{
   InitializeComponent();
}
```

This auto-generated method, in an auto-generated file, initializes my control based on designer serializiblity rules. e.g.:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
   ...
   this.lvResults = new Contoso.Controls.VirtualGrobber();
   ...

   // 
   // lvResults
   // 
   this.lvResults.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
   ...

   //FrobGrobberForm
   ...
   this.Controls.Add(this.lvResults);
   ...
}
```

How can i, a Control sitting on someone's form, know when all the designer serialization is done, and i'm "ready"?

---

In Delphi, the mechanism that serializes in a control automatically calls each control's `Loaded` method:

> Initializes the control after it is loaded from a stream.
>
> ```
> procedure Loaded; override;
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> The VCL streaming system calls Loaded
>   automatically after the control’s form is loaded into memory so that
>   the control can complete any initializations that depend on other
>   objects in the form.

Comment: There are a number of different possible ways you could do this. Which one is idiomatic or appropriate really depends on what exactly you're trying to initialize. Of course, the designer isn't doing anything magical, it's just setting properties on your control. And the standard rule of designing custom controls is that the properties should be able to be set in any order, whether by the user or by the designer.

Comment: Implement the ISupportInitialize interface.

Comment: @HansPassant <strike>i implemented ISupportInitialize, and put code in EndInit(), but it's never called. Should implementing ISupportInitialize do something?</strike> i take it back. Once you build *twice*, the designer adds a call to `EndInit()` during `InitializeComponent`. Really should phrase that in the form of an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the [`ISupportInitialize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isupportinitialize.aspx) interface. Visual Studio will add code to the form designer code file that calls [`EndInit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isupportinitialize.endinit.aspx) when it's done setting all the component's properties.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you ask about the WinForms `Control` class: You can override the [`Control.OnControlCreated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.oncreatecontrol.aspx) method. Another option is to override the [`Control.OnHandleCreated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onhandlecreated.aspx) method which is invoked when the underlying graphical object has been created.

Answer (score 0):

And also... you can detect it on `ParentChanged` event

```
private void VirtualGrobber_ParentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Form frm = this.FindForm();
        if (frm != null && !frm.IsDisposed)
            frm.Load += new EventHandler(frm_Load);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}

private void frm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do what you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want some code executed when the `Control` is "ready":

If you want it executed immediately when the `Control` is "ready", even before the form is shown: add that code after the `InitializeComponent();` in the form's constructor. (It's simply a method which creates the `Control`'s etc.)

If you want it executed when the form is shown, add:

```
Shown += Form1_Shown;
```

In the form's constructor, and:

```
void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //code to execute.
}
```

In the form's class.